# Format of \autoref for subfigures

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, autoref

I am using `\autoref` to cite figures in my document.

Here is an example with codes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}} % the counter style
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig},labelsep=space} % other settings

\begin{document}
    \section{Title of Section}
    \par Fig \autoref{subfigure1} is the first subfigure, Fig \autoref{subfigure2} is the second subfigure, and they are in \autoref{figures}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Subfigure 1]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{subfigure1}}
        \subfloat[Subfigure 2]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{subfigure2}}
        \caption{Figure} \label{figures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The document is in the following picture.

[image]

It can be seen that the subfigures are cited as Fig 1-1a and Fig 1-1b. While it there some methods to cite them as Fig 1-1(a) and Fig 1-2(b) as they appear in captions?

Comment: Both subfig and subcapton provide two labels.  That is `\label{foo}` will support `\ref{foo}` and `\subref{foo}`  (or `\ref{sub@foo}`).  Subcaption (which also supports `\subfloat`) gives more control using refformat and subrefformat options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection-\arabic{figure}} % the counter style

\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont={bf},name={Fig},labelsep=space} % other settings
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}

\begin{document}
    \section{Title of Section}
    \par Fig \autoref{subfigure1} is the first subfigure, Fig \autoref{subfigure2} is the second subfigure, and they are in \autoref{figures}
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \subfloat[Subfigure 1]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{subfigure1}}
        \subfloat[Subfigure 2]{\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{subfigure2}}
        \caption{Figure} \label{figures}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]